# Multiple worker threads vs One worker with async/await

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

My code currently has the following 10 worker threads. Each worker thread continues polling a job from the queue and then process the long running job.

```
for (int k=0; k<10; k++)
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoPollingThenWork(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void DoPollingThenWork()
{
  while (true)
  {
    var msg = Poll();
    if (msg != null)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(3000); // process the I/O bound job
    }
  }
}
```

I am refactoring the underlying code to use async/await pattern. I think I can rewrite the above code to the followings. It uses one main thread that keeps creating the async task, and use SemaphoreSlim to throttle the number of concurrent tasks to 10.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WorkerMainAsync(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

async Task WorkerMainAsync()
{
  SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
  while (true)
  {
    await ss.WaitAsync();
    Task.Run(async () => 
              {
                await DoPollingThenWorkAsync();
                ss.Release();
              });
  }
}

async Task DoPollingThenWorkAsync()
{
  var msg = Poll();
  if (msg != null)
  {
    await Task.Delay(3000); // process the I/O-bound job
  }
}
```

Both should behave the same. But I think the second options seems better because it doesn't block the thread. But the downside is I can't do Wait (to gracefully stop the task) since the task is like fire and forget. Is the second option the right way to replace the traditional worker threads pattern?

Comment: [You should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). One improvement this will get you is an automatic unwrapping of the inner task (thus, `Wait` will work as expected).

Comment: Yes, so in the sample the Task.Factory.StartNew is only used in the top-level caller to create a long-running background worker thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have code that's asynchronous, you usually have no reason to use `Task.Run()` (or, even worse, `Task.Factory.StartNew()`). This means that you can change your code to something like this:

```
await WorkerMainAsync();

async Task WorkerMainAsync()
{
  SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
  while (true)
  {
    await ss.WaitAsync();
    // you should probably store this task somewhere and then await it
    var task = DoPollingThenWorkAsync();
  }
}

async Task DoPollingThenWorkAsync(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
  var msg = Poll();
  if (msg != null)
  {
    await Task.Delay(3000); // process the I/O-bound job
  }

  // this assumes you don't have to worry about exceptions
  // otherwise consider try-finally
  semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. However in the very top-level caller, I can't use await since there is no async modifier. So I still need to have Task.Run(async () => await WorkerMainAsync()) as the entry point of the worker.

Comment: @Hengyi Not really, depending on the kind of application you're writing you can: 1. Make your top level caller `async` too (e.g. `async void` event handler in UI application). 2. Synchronously wait (`WorkerMainAsync().Wait()`). This partially defeats the purpose of `async`, but it can make sense when you need to synchronously wait. 3. Don't wait at all (just `WorkerMainAsync()`). This means you're not going to learn about exceptions in that method and it can also mean that your application exits before the worker completes.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't use `async/await` *inside* a CPU-bound task. The method that starts such a task (`WorkerMainAsync`) can use `async/await`, but you should be tracking pending tasks:

```
async Task WorkerMainAsync()
{
  SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
  List<Task> trackedTasks = new List<Task>();
  while (DoMore())
  {
    await ss.WaitAsync();
    trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => 
              {
                DoPollingThenWorkAsync();
                ss.Release();
              }));
  }
  await Task.WhenAll(trackedTasks);
}

void DoPollingThenWorkAsync()
{
  var msg = Poll();
  if (msg != null)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(2000); // process the long running CPU-bound job
  }
}
```

Another exercise would be to remove tasks from `trackedTasks` as they are finishing. For example, you could use `ContinueWith` to remove a finished tasks (in this case, remember to use `lock` to protect `trackedTasks` from simultaneous access).

If you really need to use `await` inside `DoPollingThenWorkAsync`, the code wouldn't change a lot:

```
    trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => 
              {
                await DoPollingThenWorkAsync();
                ss.Release();
              }));
```

Note that in this case, you'd be dealing [with a nested task](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) here for the async lambda, which `Task.Run` will automatically unwrap for you.

Comment: The work is mostly IO bound. async lambda with trackedTasks works. I have  var t = Task.Run(async lambda); trackedTasks.Add(t); t.ContinueWith(RemoveTask). So the second option looks good now. Any other pitfalls?

Comment: If the work is mostly IO-bound, I'd suggest using the pattern proposed by svick. Note however, `await` captures the execution context by default (see `Task.ConfigureAwait`). So if you do async IO-bound calls on the UI thread, and still do some CPU-bound work between the IO-bound calls which keeps the thread busy for more than 50ms, such task may be a good candidate for `Task.Run`.